# create a menu dynamically to import in different web pages

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

I'm creating a app with cordova framework, I want to create a main menu generated dinamically with javascript which I can import in different web pages.

I have the next folder structure

```
|-folder
|--index.html
|--|reports
|--|--index.html
|--|--report.html
|--js
|--|--menu.js
```

So If I create the menu from index.html importing the script menu.js the result would be something like

```
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="reports/index.html">Reports</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

the other hand if I import the script from reports/index.html the href in the items would change.

This could be done easily with some MVC Framework, but the project use only JQuery and I don't want to incorporate whole project to a Framework. Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on exastion's answer, I created a menu.js script and inside this I detected the path of script putting in the menu items absolute path names, this is the script:

```
 var scripts     = document.getElementsByTagName('script'),
     basedir     = scripts[scripts.length-1].src.slice(0, -10);
     //quit the script name and folder js 


$('body').append('<div class="overlay-menu"></div>'+
                        '<div class="menu">'+
                        '<ul><li><a href="'+basedir+'index.html">Inicio</a></li>'+
                        '<ul><li><a href="'+basedir+'reports/index.html">Inicio</a></li>'+
                        '</ul></div>');
```

Answer (score 2):

You could simply use absolute path names

```
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
   <li><a href="/folder/.../index.html">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="/folder/.../reports/index.html">Reports</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

If this is only for small HTML-only sites, I would go with that solution, but if you’re planning sth. bigger, use some php to detect the current page, or even better use some sort of framework that does this for you.

Comment: this works if I would have the folder in the root of my disk, How can I detect where "folder" directory is located from script?

Comment: As far as I know this is not possible with HTML alone

Comment: I want to do throught Javascript, generate the menu depending of import in each page

Comment: I'm creating this for a Cordova app, so my best option is Javascript